# Ridge regression not working for very simple dataset (yet exact same code works on another dataset)

Tags: r, regression, ridge-regression

I found some R code for performing ridge regression on the BostonHousing dataset. I tried to use the exact same code on some simple artifical data but it fails and I get the error message: `Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing`

Here is the regression code. Why does it work for the BostonHousing dataset but not the simple artificial dataset?

```
################################################################################
# Ridge regression on BostonHousing dataset
################################################################################
library("caret")
library('mlbench')
data(BostonHousing)

#split data
split <- createDataPartition(y=BostonHousing$medv, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)

#create training and test sets
train <- BostonHousing[split,]
test <- BostonHousing[-split,]

#calculate ridge regression on every lambda with the training set
ridge <- train(medv ~., data = train, method='ridge',
    lambda = 4,preProcess=c('scale', 'center'))

################################################################################
# Ridge regression on simple artificial dataset
################################################################################
n = 100
X_p_mean = 12
X_p_var = 4
eps_mean = 0
eps_var = 4
beta_1 = 2
eps <- rnorm(n,eps_mean,sqrt(eps_var))
X <- rnorm(n,X_p_mean,sqrt(X_p_var))
Y <- beta_1*X + eps
df_X_Y = data.frame(X,Y)

#split data
split <- createDataPartition(y=df_X_Y$Y, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)

#create training and test sets
train <- df_X_Y[split,]
test <- df_X_Y[-split,]

#calculate ridge regression on every lambda with the training set
ridge <- train(Y ~ ., data = train, method='ridge',
    lambda = 4, preProcess=c('scale', 'center'))
```

Comment: List all of the libraries you use - what package is createDataPartition from?

Comment: @alanocallaghan I edited the post to add the caret library which is what I use for createDataPartition. Caret and mlbench are the only packages I'm using.

Comment: Ridge regression equates to Weighted Least-Squares (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares). The latter is equal to LS on transformed (via a weight-related to the inverse of expected precision for that point). Try solving this LS problem in a spreadsheet setting to be able to understand (or see as perhaps a zero weighting issue) that is causing a matrix inversion (singularity) issue.

Comment: I have just checked what happens if I reduced the number of columns in the BostonHousing dataset from 14 to 2, which is the number of columns in the simple dataset. I use `BostonHousing <- BostonHousing[c("age","medv")]` - it turns out that if I do this I get the same errors as I get for the simple artificial problem. This is very strange, surely the number of columns shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Actually, re-thinking, for now ignore the weighting issue, can you put your model in a form (including any required dummy variables) where you can run a LS regression? If that produces a problem, you have an experimental design issue (perhaps over specification). See https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/ .

Comment: OLS regression works fine. This is a very simple setting with one response variable and one predictor variable. Regression doesn't get much simpler than this. It seems like a software/library issue. I am hoping someone with experience of performing ridge regression in R can explain why the code doesn't work. Since the problem is so simple, there is no obvious reason why this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ridge regression and lasso and the like are all used to attend model selection tasks and are not necessarily coded for a univariable use-case. If you want to do a univariable regression, you could try to use [`parcor::lm.ridge.univariate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/parcor/man/lm.ridge.univariate.html).

If you attempt to do univariable ridge regression (predictor matrix `X` is a vector) with the function that `caret` calls: `cv.glmnet(X, Y, ..., alpha = 0)` you get the error: `Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,: x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns`.

As far as I can tell, the methods you're trying to use do not support a univariable ridge regression. [Here is a github pull request attempting to integrate support.](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/pull/1)

Comment: This might be a silly question (and its only slightly related to the actual question above), given a simple linear regression Y~X1, would ridge regression be any different than OLS? I'm not as familiar with ridge/lasso, but my cursory knowledge tells me they are almost exclusively used in regressions with multiple predictors (and often large sets of predictors).

Comment: I think it may penalize your singular predictor and you could end up with no non-zero estimates. I haven't been able to find any literature that motivates doing it for a single factor.